# No unique bean of type [org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 3

Tags: spring

I am having the following mapping for the one of the spring bean in my mapping-xml.Then when I am trying to @Autowired "ClassParent" in one of my junit-test class I am getting exception as "org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 3"

## The Mapping is :

```
<bean id="ClassParent"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper">
        <property name="tokenizers">
            <map>
                <entry key="D*" value-ref="ClassC" />
                <entry key="T*" value-ref="ClassD" />
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="fieldSetMappers">
            <map>
                <entry key="D*" value-ref="ClassA" />
                <entry key="T*" value-ref="ClassB" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

How I can autowired the bean "ClassParent" please help me.

Answer (score 2):

it try to find the injected bean definition and finds three beans.you have to specify name attribute with resource annotation and give the id of the bean which you want to inject with that particular instance, in name attriburte

```
@Resouce(name="classparentId")
@Autowired
```

See [Problem with Autowiring & No unique bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699608/problem-with-autowiring-no-unique-bean)