# org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [org.quartz.JobDetail] is defined

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, quartz-scheduler

I get the following exception when running my Spring application:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of 
type [org.quartz.JobDetail] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: 
[quartzSchedulerRuntime, jobDetail]
```

This is part where I configure quartz in `root-context.xml`.

**root-context.xml**

```
<bean name="quartzSchedulerRuntime" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
    <property name="jobClass" value="com.task.QuartzScheduler" />
    <property name="jobDataAsMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="runtimeReportServiceImpl" value-ref="RuntimeReportService"  />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean> 


    <bean id="cronTriggerRuntime"
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">

        <property name="jobDetail" ref="quartzSchedulerRuntime" />
        <property name="cronExpression" value="0 30 12 ? * MON *" />

</bean>


    <bean id="quartzScheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean" lazy-init="false">
    <property name="schedulerContextAsMap">
        <map>
        <entry key="reportSchedulerServiceImpl" value-ref="reportSchedulerServiceImpl"></entry>
        </map>
        </property>
    <property name="jobDetails">
       <list>
          <ref bean="quartzSchedulerRuntime" />
          <ref bean="jobDetail"/>
       </list>
    </property>

    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
        <ref bean="cronTriggerRuntime" />
        <ref bean="jobTrigger"/>
        </list>
    </property>

    </bean>

    <bean id="jobDetailFactory"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ObjectFactoryCreatingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetBeanName">
        <idref local="jobDetail" />
    </property>

    </bean>

    <bean id="jobDetail" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean"
    scope="prototype">
    <property name="jobClass" value="com.scheduler.SMTPMailJob " />

     <property name="jobDataAsMap">
        <map>
          <entry key="reportSchedulerServiceImpl" value-ref="reportSchedulerServiceImpl" />
          <entry key="filterUtil" value-ref="filterUtil" />
          <entry key="reportService" value-ref="reportService" />
          <entry key="fusionChartHtmlToImage" value-ref="fusionChartHtmlToImage"/>
          <entry key="fcproperties" value-ref="fcproperties"/>
         </map>
      </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jobTriggerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ObjectFactoryCreatingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetBeanName">
        <idref local="jobTrigger" />
    </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jobTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean" scope="prototype">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="jobDetail" />
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0 9 1/1 * ? *" /> 
    </bean>
```

**EDIT:** I have narrowed down the problem to this. I have created a class called RScheduler that is supposed to schedule the jobs. In that class I have declared:

```
Scheduler scheduler;
ObjectFactory<JobDetail> jobDetailFactory;
ObjectFactory<CronTrigger> jobTriggerFactory;

    @Autowired
    public ReportScheduler(Scheduler scheduler,ObjectFactory<JobDetail> jobDetailFactory,ObjectFactory<CronTrigger> jobTriggerFactory)
            throws SchedulerException 
            {
        Assert.notNull(scheduler, "scheduler cannot be null");
        Assert.notNull(jobDetailFactory, "jobDetailFactory cannot be null");
        Assert.notNull(jobTriggerFactory, "jobTriggerFactory cannot be null");
        this.scheduler = scheduler;
        this.jobDetailFactory=jobDetailFactory;
        this.jobTriggerFactory=jobTriggerFactory;
        this.scheduler.getContext().put("reportSchedulerServ", reportSchedulerServ);
        }
```

I am calling the job in another method like:

```
JobDetail jobDetail = jobDetailFactory.getObject();
```

This is the line giving me the error.

**EDIT 2:** I am guessing the problem is that I require many jobs to be triggered. So i have created the

`ObjectFactory<JobDetail> jobDetailFactory`

to capture objects via the `jobDetailFactory` bean. I think , the line

`JobDetail jobDetail = jobDetailFactory.getObject()`

isn't able to figure out which JobDetail bean to get, since it has two job details. I don't understand how the `@Qualifier` notation will help in determining that. Any particular way in which I can resolve this error..?

Comment: Are you autowiring your beans by 'type' anywhere in your entire spring context?

Comment: where is your `jobDetail` bean definition. can you add that also to your question.

Comment: It's provided in the root-context.

Answer (score 0):

check if you have given the same bean name(duplicated) @type("bean name here") on both job detail bean

EDIT- can you share the jobdetail (SMTPMailJob and QuartzScheduler) bean classes here. i dont see any issue with the xml configuration

add `@Qualifier` annotation where ever you are auto-wiring jobdetail bean

For instance

if you are auto-wiring Quartzscheduler then

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier(Quartzscheduler)
public JobDetail quartzSchedulerbean
```

since you have two job-detail bean , at run time spring doesn't know which bean to be wired because we refer the beans of its type. so adding @Qualifier annotation will tell spring to auto-wire specific bean instance.

Update :- since the code you have shared doesnt give me more input, the basic problem from the exception what you are getting as i said in above statement.

1. you have two jobdetails of type `quartz.jobdetail`
2. you have one jobdetail in jobdetail factory.

ok, you said that you are getting exception when you do objectFactory.getObject() which means point no 2, in this case you should not get the exception mentioned in the question, because you have only one bean in the jobdetail factory. 
As per my understanding you should get exception while autowiring jobdetails defined in schedulerbeanfactory not in objectfactory object.

EDIT - check this link [Problem with Autowiring & No unique bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699608/problem-with-autowiring-no-unique-bean)

Comment: kindly check edit 2. I do not have any other declarations of `jobDetail` apart from that single line of code.

Answer (score 0):

as you can see, you define two beans that have the same type:

jobDetail and quartzSchedulerRuntime are of the type 
org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean

You can distinguish them by their name (quartzSchedulerRuntime / jobDetail), but if you autowire them by Type (...JobDetailBean) it's ambigious.

Comment: Assuming that you are using a construct like:
@Autowire
JobDetailBean jobDetails;

then you may change it to 
@Resource(name="jobDetail")
JobDetailBean jobDetails;