# Spring & No unique bean of type

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I have the following Beans for Spring based unit test:

```
abstract class A {
    // some injections using @Value
}

class B extends A {
    // some injections using @Autowired, @Qualifier, @PersistenceUnit and @Value
}

class C extends A {
    // some injections using @Autowired, @Qualifier, @PersistenceUnit and @Value
}

class Foo{

    @Autowired
    private A a;

    ...
}

class BarTest{

    @Autowired
    private B b;

    @Autowired
    private C c;

    @Autowired // Expected: fooB.a = b
    private Foo fooB;

    @Autowired // Expected: fooC.a = c
    private Foo fooC;

    ...
}
```

In class BarTest: is it possible to control what gets injected into the 2 instances of Foo?

Or do I have a design issue and I should setup things differently?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem with Autowiring & No unique bean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699608/problem-with-autowiring-no-unique-bean)

Comment: @nobeh No, I think this is a different issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control what gets injected via **qualifiers**.

But in this case your `Foo` class will not be a singleton. So, most likely you will have to instantiate (at least - depending on your needs) two `Foo` objects via XML.

Like this:

```
<beans ... >
    <bean id="b" class="your.pack.B" >
    <bean id="c" class="your.pack.C" >
    <bean id="fooB" class="your.pack.Foo" >
        <property name="a" ref="b" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="fooC" class="your.pack.Foo" >
        <property name="a" ref="c" />
    </bean>

...
</beans>
```

-

```
@Autowired // Expected: fooB.a = b
@Qualifier("fooB")
private Foo fooB;

@Autowired // Expected: fooB.a = c
@Qualifier("fooC")
private Foo fooC;
```

(And get rid of the `@Autowired` annotation in `Foo` class)

Comment: Yes, that's what I was affraid of. But in this case I can just set Foo.a programmatically in the setup/@Before method of the BarTest (JUnit test) class and omit the @Autowired annotation as well as the XML configuration.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to `@Qualifier` you can use `javax.annotation.Resource` annotation

```
@Resource(name = "fooB")
private Foo fooB;

@Resource(name = "fooC")
private Foo fooC;
```

Comment: Injecting B is not the problem here, but Foo.a (2 different instances).

Comment: Why do you recommend Resource over Qualifier here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the  [`@Qualifier`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s11.html)

```
@Qualifier("C")
@Autowired
private C c;

@Qualifier("B")
@Autowired
private B b;
```

Comment: The qulifier for c and b is not necessary here because there is only one type of B and C. The problem is with Foo.