# Why do I get a "No unique bean is defined" in one place, but not another?

Tags: java, spring

A colleague has written two sessionFactory definitions in a servlet.xml file for the same class.

They do not, however, qualify which one to use every time they autowire a property of that type. When they want to use the second version, they add @Qualifier, but in all other instances they just @Autowire, and it seems to use the first definition.

I have tried to do the same, for another class where I have a special case, and I want it built in a different way. However, I get:

> NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean ... is defined: expected
>   single matching bean but found 2

Other people have the same problem, and the answer seems to be to be explicit everywhere (that is a lot of places in the code I am working on), for example here:

[Problem with Autowiring & No unique bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699608/problem-with-autowiring-no-unique-bean)

but am I missing something? Is there some default behaviour?

Thanks

**edit**

AnnotationSessionFactoryBean is defined twice.

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocations" value="classpath*:/hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.use_scrollable_resultset">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">${hibernate.cache.provider_class}</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.memcached.servers">${hibernate.memcached.servers}</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="sessionFactoryWritable" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceWritable" />
    <property name="configLocations" value="classpath*:/hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">${hibernate.cache.provider_class}</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.memcached.servers">${hibernate.memcached.servers}</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

In code, sometimes this is written:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("sessionFactoryWritable")
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

other times this:

```
@Autowired
protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

**more information**

SessionFactory actually refers to an interface (org.hibernate.SessionFactory), but the bean definitions of course refer to an actual class.

In my case I was auto-wiring a class, with no interface, and nothing actually defined in the config. Once I added an entry in the config (to define a second set up with some different properties), I got the error.

**related?**

The class I was trying to create had the following attribute:

```
org.springframework.stereotype.Repository
```

I am not sure why it had this, but I would like confirmation that having this is at least equivalent to writing a bean definition in the config file (the documentation does not state so as far as I can understand, but that is the behavior I find).

Comment: Can you share the configuration file ?

Comment: As a side note, most places where people use `@Autowired` (which is used for dependency injection by type) and `@Qualifier`, it's to use the bean's ID as the qualifier criteria, and in those cases the right annotation is actually `@Resource` (which is used for dependency injection by ID).

Comment: Are you sure that when they don't use `@Qualifier`, both beans are actually created?  It might be that when they want the overridden one, they specifically load a Spring config file that defines the alternate bean (which then requires them to use `@Qualifier`), but the rest of the time they only define one bean of that type so they don't need to bother with `@Qualifier`.  I've never seen Spring not complain when asked to `@Autowire` with more than one bean matching that type, so I suspect you've misunderstood what your coworkers are doing rather than that Spring is behaving unpredictably.

Comment: The behavior you see in your case is the correct one. Analyze carefully the other scenario of your colleague, because Spring doesn't simply pick the first one or something, it will complain if it's more than one match or no matches.

Comment: I agree with @Andrei Stefan your colleagues must have strategy to manage the conflicting autowire candidates. Check that the AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor is not overriden or that they are not using autowire-candidate bean property. There are other many ways to affect the autowiring strategy.

Answer (score 1):

My working example is for multiple hibernate, I wish it will be usefull for you.

Data source

```
 <!-- DATA SOURCE -->
    <bean id="_dataSourceProxy"
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
       <property name="resourceRef" value="true" />
       <property name="jndiName" value="${connection.jndiName}"></property>
       <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false"></property>
       <property name="cache" value="false"></property>
       <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.sql.DataSource"></property>
    </bean>
```

Hibernate

```
 <!-- HIBERNATE -->
 <bean id="_hibernateSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="_dataSourceProxy"></ref>
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.SetBigStringTryClob">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">0</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.use_streams_for_binary">false</prop>
            <prop key="javax.persistence.validation.mode">none</prop>
            <prop key="connection.useUnicode">true</prop>   
            <prop key="connection.characterEncoding">utf-8</prop>


            <prop key="hibernate.connection.defaultNChar">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>

        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>hibernate/content/Content.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>hibernate/content/ContentMeta.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>

</bean>
```

Hibernate Conf for multi

```
 <!-- Content Repo -->
    <bean id="_contentRepository"
        class="XXXX">
        <aop:scoped-proxy/>
        <property name="_senderEmail" value="${smtp.senderEmail}"></property>    
        <property name="_hibernateSessionFactory">
            <ref bean="_hibernateSessionFactory"></ref>
        </property>
        <property name="_authService">
            <ref bean="_authService"></ref>
        </property>   
        <property name="_languageRepository">
            <ref bean="_languageRepository"></ref>
        </property>  
        <property name="_locationRepository">
            <ref bean="_locationRepository"></ref>
        </property>          
        <property name="_velocityEngine">
            <ref bean="_velocityEngine"></ref>
        </property>
        <property name="_mailSender">
            <ref bean="_mailSender"></ref>
        </property>                                                   
    </bean>
```

Example repo:

```
<!-- Location Repo -->
    <bean id="_locationRepository"
        class="XXXX">
        <property name="_hibernateSessionFactory">
            <ref bean="_hibernateSessionFactory"></ref>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are my (possibly incorrect) conclusions:

The sessionFactory example worked because an interface was used in code. The only link between the interface and the bean configuration was that the variable name was the same as the bean's id (sessionFactory). A @Qualifier over rules the variable name, hence the  sessionFactoryWritable worked.

My example was failing because I referred to a class. The name of the variable seems to be ignored (why?).

- I created an interface, and used that through out my code
- Two been configurations with different ids but referring to the same class (which implements the interface)
- The name of the variable to be @Autowired matches the id of the bean configuration
- In cases when I want to use a different object, I can use a @Resource attribute (or @Autowired and @Qualified) to specify which one

That seems to work. I have 1 interface implemented by 1 class, and two bean definitions. I do not need to mark the variables with @Qualified (or specify the name via @Resource) if the variable name matches the id.

Answer (score -1):

As long as spring only finds one matching interface in its current it will work out of the box.

When using the `@Qualifier` you can filter what is used.

For one of my projects had two bean definitions. One was the usual and one was for testing which was only available during tests. I added a [@Primary](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html) and my test definition got precedence. In your case it would be `<bean primary="true|false"/>` however you should use the qualifier.

You find a documentation in the [spring reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-autowire).